# WPF datagrid lost scrollbar inside a viewbox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I got a a few Textblocks and a Datagrid in a grid. The Datagrid vertical scrollbar works fine. But when I put the grid inside a Viewbox the vertical scrollbar disappears. Below is my code

```
<Window x:Class=MyProject.View.MyTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
             Title="{Binding FormTitle}" Height="500" Width="800" >

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F7" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="UniformToFill" >
        <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Name="rootGrid">
            <TextBlock Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Job ID:" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
            <TextBlock Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,28,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Job Run Time:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,45,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Run Number:"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,61,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="User Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ArchInfo}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="True" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
              ColumnHeaderHeight ="40"

              Margin="5,124,5,0" IsReadOnly="True">
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table Name"  Binding="{Binding Path=TableName,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table Type"  Binding="{Binding Path=TableType,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"      Binding="{Binding Path=Status,     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
              </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

If I add the following to the Datagrid the scrollbar will show but it does not function.

```
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

No matter what I do I can only see part of the Datagrid rows.
Any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks,

Comment: Is the viewbox just stretching to make the datagrid as big as it can? try setting a height on the datagrid

Comment: Also check that the uniform to fill isn't causing the scroll bar to move off the edge of the viewbox, change it to fill

Comment: Andy, you are right. Setting Datagrid Height and Stretch="Uniform" made it work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by Andy's comment.

Setting Datagrid Height and Stretch="Uniform" made it work. See Andy's comment.